# Como mandar um email depois que o cadastro de usuário foi feito? Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, envio-de-email, laravel-5.3

Preciso que quando um usuario for cadastrado ele pegue o valor do campo email e passe para a função `$message->to($request->email)` para mandar o email para o usuário cadastrado.Veja como estou fazendo. Só que no objeto `$message->to()` não esta sendo dinamicamente. Como eu faço para ser dinâmico com os dados vindo do Request?

```
Mail::send('email.send', ['title' => 'Cadastro de usuario de email', 'content' => 'teste teste'], function ($message)
            {

                $message->from('natan.suporte@hotmail.com', 'Natan Melo');

                $message->to('usuario@usuario.com.br');

            });
```

so que nesse objeto $massage->to(aqui tinha que ser dinâmico)
Tipo assim `$message->to($request->email)` //email vindo do formulário. Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para essa finalidade você pode utilizar os gatilhos do próprio Laravel, estou me referindo aos [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers). Uma das vantagens é que você já vai está utilizando algo pronto, que faz parte do core do Laravel. Sem falar é claro que Observers permite que você dispare email automático em outras situações também.

Primeiramente criamos o arquivo: **App\Observers\ObservarUser.php** com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\User;
use App\Notifications\NotificarNovoUsuario;

    class ObservarUser
    {
        /**
         * Listen to the User created event.
         *
         * @param  User  $user
         * @return void
         */
        public function created(User $user)
        {
            $user->notify(new NotificarNovoUsuario());
        }

        /**
         * Listen to the User deleting event.
         *
         * @param  User  $user
         * @return void
         */
        public function deleting(User $user)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Observe que além do created você tem outros possíveis métodos que podem ser utilizados seguindo a mesma lógica.

E agora criamos uma:

```
php artisan make:notification NotificarNovoUsuario
```

Isso irá gerar o arquivo **App\Notifications\NotificarNovoUsuario.php** com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class NotificarNovoUsuario extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {   
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject('Seja bem-vindo ao ' . config('app.name'))
                    ->line('É com grande alegria que te damos as boas vindas!')
                    ->action('Clique aqui para acessar ', url('/'))
                    ->line('Qualquer dúvida nossa equipe está sempre a disposição!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

A única coisa que fiz foi modificar o método **toMail** para inserir minha própria mensagem.

E por fim você edita seu **App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php** e altera o método **boot** para:

```
public function boot()
{
    User::observe(ObservarUser::class);
}
```

Comment: Cara que bacana isso ai que você me ensinou. Sou muito grato. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Mais onde onde fica essa conf. . config('app.name') ?

Comment: Dentro do arquivo .env você tem uma linha com o nome do seu aplicativo, não lembro o nome do parâmetro de cabeça, mas acho que é a primeira linha, esse conf(‘app.name’) pode ser sobrescrito lá. Ou até mesmo dentro do arquivo config/app.php

Comment: Pois é eu dei uma olhada e é isso mesmo. vlw Deu certinho para o que eu quero. Obg mesmo

Comment: E vc mora aqui do lado em Em Brasilia , sou aqui de Luziania. Vlw

Comment: Show de bola então. Qualquer coisa estamos por ai. Subi um projeto em Laravel no meu Github caso queira conferir: github.com/fabiojaniolima/WebUpload

Comment: add para nos trocar umas ideias. fb.com/natan.suporte